# get "success" without receiving any message with GCM

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-messaging

I've tried to send a notification from server to my app on my phone and I get "success" but my phone doesn't receive anything, I'm using Google Cloud Messaging

```
public class GCMIntentService extends GcmListenerService{


private static final String TAG = "GCMIntentService";

@Override
public void onMessageReceived(String from, Bundle data) {

    String message = data.getString("message");
    Log.d(TAG, "from:" + from);
    Log.d(TAG, "message:" + message);

    sendNotification(message);
}
 private void sendNotification(String message){
 Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
 intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
 PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

 Uri defaultSound = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
 if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP){

 NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.logo)
                .setContentTitle("New Message")
                .setContentText(message)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setSound(defaultSound)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
notificationManager.notify(0, notificationBuilder.build());

    }

}
}
```

AndroidManifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />

<permission android:name="com.example.abdul_majeed.alruthea.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
```

android:protectionLevel="signature" />

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.example.abdul_majeed.alruthea.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

....

<receiver
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmReceiver"
        android:exported="true"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">      
<intent-filter>
<action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
<category android:name="com.example.abdul_majeed.alruthea" />
</intent-filter>  

</receiver>   
    <service
        android:name=".GCMIntentService"
        android:exported="false">
<intent-filter>
<action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
</intent-filter>
</service>
```

================================================

Comment: Any response please, are my codes ok?

Answer (score 0):

The problem “... doesn't receive anything …” may have caused by the code 
below:

```
if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP){... ...
```

This means that if your device is lower than  LOLLIPOP,then you can receive  anything,
and if your device is higher than LOLLIPOP,then you can’t receive  anything. Please check the Android version of the phone you are using.